# Why is Certbot renew giving "bad handhake" error?

Tags: ssl, certbot

I recently tried to renew my certificates for a web server I run and I am getting the below error::

```
SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

I saw some posts on the community page but nothing seemed to be exactly what my problem was.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was because the clock on the server I was logged into had drifted by over a year because ntp was not installed.

I installed ntp, the date and time updated correctly and I was able to renew my certificates.

Answer (score 13):

I faced with the same issue today, and this [answer](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificate-verify-failed/64848/7) helped me:

I also re-installed `ca-certificates` package and `certbot renew` works now.

For Ubuntu / Debian

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```